# Site broken after upgrading with Pathauto < 8.x-1.6

Tags: 8, updating

I recently upgraded to Drupal 8.8. Unfortunately I missed the memo on needing to upgrade Pathauto first and now my site is broken. Most pages give the message "The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later."

I can get to /user and log in with an admin account, and I can get to /update.php which tells me "The Pathauto module is not compatible with the current version of Drupal core. Update the Pathauto module to 8.x-1.6 or later." and does not give me the option to continue to database updates.

I can't get to many other pages, and notably can't get to /admin/modules where I would normally upgrade a specific out of date module like Pathauto.

Do I have any other options besides wipe my site and restore from a backup? Even if I can figure out how to upgrade Pathauto at this point, I'm not clear if that's likely to fix the issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Upload the latest version of Pathauto via FTP. Or however your host allows you to update single modules. Then run database updates. And then please update your question with the outcome. Many thanks

Comment: @leymannx Thanks for the suggestion. I've tried that and although I've got the latest version of Pathauto uploaded now, the update.php page is still reporting it as out of date. Is there some extra step required to make the update script "notice" the new version I've uploaded?

Comment: You should have replaced the old Pathauto version. Did this happen? Flush caches first and then run update.php.

Comment: @leymannx OK, I tried again per the update above and my site is back up again. If you want to take my update and re-post as an answer I will accept it. If not, I will do that myself in a few days so this shows as answered. Many thanks!

Comment: You're the expert now so please add and accept an answer yourself. Glad it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments above from leymannx, I've manually uploaded Pathauto 1.6 to my site via FTP. Returning to /update.php, I got the option to update the database and that worked and my site is back up again.

Note: The first time I tried this, I renamed the old Pathauto module folder to "pathauto_old", and uploaded the new version to a newly created folder just called "pathauto", and that did not work. update.php continued to report and out of date Pathauto. After that, I deleted both folders, re-uploaded pathauto 1.6, and then it worked.